# Get each value's difference from overall min value in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of data that is in timestamp with time zone format (called "time"). I also have an empty table that takes in interval data type values. For each row in the empty table, I want to insert the interval difference between that row's timestamp in the original data and the overall minimum timestamp value in the original data. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO
    time_pyramid
SELECT
    "time" - MIN("time")
FROM
    time_raw;
```

But it tells me "ERROR: column "time_raw.time" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function". I know I want each timestamp value's interval difference from the table's overall minimum timestamp value, and "time" is not going to end up having duplicate values from this interval conversion, so I don't really think I should use GROUP BY in that context. I also see no reason to use an aggregation function on the first "time", so how can I fix my query to reflect what I want?

Edit: Actually, "Get each value as its interval difference from the min" is a better title for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min()` as a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
with time_raw("time") as (
    values
        ('2016-01-11'::timestamp),
        ('2016-01-01'::timestamp),
        ('2016-01-21'::timestamp)
)

select 
    "time"- min("time") over () as interval
from 
    time_raw;

 interval 
----------
 10 days
 00:00:00
 20 days
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Wow I guess I will have to read up on window functions. Thank you, this is what I needed.

Comment: Note that `min("time") over ()` is syntactically indivisible. Use `(extract(epoch from "time"- min("time") over ())* 1000000)::bigint`.

Comment: Yes I found out to put the over () inside by moving around the parentheses. It'll be good for me to remember to tie the window function to the aggregate.